# Is it possible for an NT Service logOn account to have a suffix other than the service name?

Tags: windows, services, naming

In Windows services, we can see certain services has logOn types as NT Service. In most cases, this type of logOn accounts are named NT Service, followed by a slash, and and the name of the specific service,  *i.e. NT Service<serviceName>*. Eg: **NT Service\MSSQLSERVER**.

I'd like to know if it's possible to have a suffix other than the service name after the slash.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I saw this question a couple of days ago.

Comment: @John But I couldn't find the answer I'm looking for. I just want to confirm whether only the service name is suffixed after NT Service. That's why I thought of asking it here.

Comment: It probably would have been better to stick with the original question if you can.